# CNN for a DQN agent with a 2D matrix state and action as a 2D matrix

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have a custom environment, where the state is a 2D matrix of 11 rows (equals to number of users to satisfy) and 3 columns. Each column can take the value of either 0 or 1, and in each row, there can be only one column with the value 1.

Example of a state matrix:

```
(
 (1, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0)
)
```

The action is another 2D matrix, with 12 rows (equals total number of resources available to the agent) and 11 columns (equals number of users the agent must satisfy). The agent must choose a resource for each user. Each user can only have one resource, and each resource can be given to only one user at each time step.

Example of action matrix:

```
(
 ('O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'O', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'O', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z')
)
```

'O' stands for One, which means the resource was allocated to the user, and 'Z' stands for Zero which means that the resource wasn't allocated to the user.

`row[0] = ('O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z')`
which means resource0 is given to user0 (because `row[0][0] == 'O'`), because in the state matrix, `row[0] = (1, 0, 0)` which means that user0 is asking for a resource to be given to him.

A reward is returned by the step() method in the Reinforcement Learning environment if the agent hasn't given a resource to a user that didn't ask for a resource to be given. Otherwise, a penalty is returned.

In other words, the state matrix has `row[1] = (0, 0, 0)`; if, say, in the action matrix `row[1] = ('Z', 'O', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z')`, then resource1 is allocated to user1 (because `row[1][1] == 'O'`), but user1 didn't ask for a resource, hence a penalty is returned.

The reward varies depending on which column is equal to 1 in each row in the state matrix.

I am trying to create a CNN where the input is the state matrix and the output is the action matrix. I have tried it using a convolution part followed by a de-convolution part. However, I'm failing to see how I should indicate to the neural network that for each row of the state matrix, it must choose a resource to allocate to the user if he asked for it (constraint 1), and if a resource is chosen, it is locked for that user and cannot be given to another user at that time step (constraint 2).

Here's the code so far of the CNN part:

```
def _build_model(self):
        inp = Input((11, 3, 1))     ##
        x = Conv2D(2, (2, 2))(inp) ##  Convolution part
        x = Conv2D(4, (2, 2))(x)   ##

        x = Conv2DTranspose(4, (3, 4))(x)   ##
        x = Conv2DTranspose(2, (2, 4))(x)   ##  Deconvolution part
        out = Conv2DTranspose(1, (2, 4))(x) ##

        model = Model(inp, out)
        model.summary()

        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate), loss='mean_squared_error')

        return model
```

I have no idea if what I'm doing is correct or not, and if the convolution/de-convolution method is best suitable for my problem.

Instead of having the output of the CNN as a 2D matrix, I thought I'd make the output an array with the resources numbered from 0 to 11 (12 resources), chosen by the network for each user, then manually transform it into a matrix because the environment needs it as a matrix for the reward calculation. However, I'm not sure if that's a feasible idea.